# KDE Custom shortcut to re-implementing copy paste (could DBus work ?)

Tags: dbus, kde-plasma, xclip

I'm on KDE in french and I use the *Raccourcis Personalisés* menu to create custom keyboard shortcuts, I would like <kbd>⊞ Windows+C</kbd> and <kbd>⊞ Windows+V</kbd> to be copy (bash `xclip -selection clipboard`) and paste (`xclip -selection clipboard`) but writing those commands in the menu do not work.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How to make it work, how can I have copy-paste on Windows+C and Windows+V ?

Comment: This sounds like a KDE configuration question, not a programming question, in which case it’s out of scope for StackOverflow. Why have you mentioned D-Bus in your question? I don’t see the relevance to D-Bus.

Comment: The _Custom menu_ proposes 3 choices for the shortcut, either a command (bash I guess), either a DBus command, either a text sent to the keyboard.  Well, KDE yes, in which sub-stackexchange shall I go ? :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ maybe ?

Comment: Sounds like a good bet. Good luck!